Examples of pseudofunctors into Cat
I'm trying to find (basic) examples of pseudofunctors into Cat, but the only example I keep coming across is the extension of scalars (from the functor $R\text{-Mod} \to S\text{-Mod}; M \mapsto M\otimes_R S$, induced by a ring homomorphism $R\to S$). Can anyone point me to some different examples? I'm looking specifically for those which are not true functors. For example, I think the map $F : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Cat}$ which sends an object $C \in \mathcal{C}$ to the slice category $\mathcal{C}_{/C}$ is actually a true functor, because it respects composition and identities up to actual equality. The reason I want a second example is just to motivate using Grothendieck opfibrations.

If $\mathcal{C}$ has finite limits, then the functor $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}, c\mapsto\mathcal{C}_{/c}$ which sends $f\colon c\to d$ to the pullback functor $f^*\colon\mathcal{C}_{/d}\to\mathcal{C}_{/c}$ is for instance a pseudofunctor that generally speaking we do not consider a strict functor. (Although sometimes people need to choose their pullbacks in such a way that this becomes a strict functor.)

This might be a stupid question, but why is $f^*$ a functor? If it sends an object $h : x \to d$ of $\mathcal{C}_{/d}$ to the pullback of $f$ along $h$, isn't that pullback square only defined up to isomorphism? How do you pick which pullback square to use?

Ah, nevermind! Someone asked almost exactly the same question as me on mathoverflow. I think I get it now.
